# Sort (alphabetically) a matrix of strings using a Merge Algorithm in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, matrix

I'm trying to merge a matrix (size r rows and c columns) of strings into a single array of  strings (size r*c) in an alphabetically sorted way, the problem is that my algorithm just partially sort it and doesn't get the correct value of the index of the resulting array.

The rows are themselves already sorted, that means that for every row the strings in that row are already in alphabetic order.

A sorting algorithm would be too inefficient.

Example: (of course i have to work with a larger matrix).

fbc zfb

abc tuv

Resulting array:

abc
fbc
tuv
zfb

Here is my (wrong) function:

```
void orderMat(char ***mat, int r, int co)
{
    int i,a=0,b=0,c=0; char **c1;

    c1=malloc( (r*co)*sizeof(char *) );




    for(i=0;i<(r-1);i++)
    {  a=0;b=0;
        while(a<co && b<co)
        {
            if(strcmp(mat[i][a],mat[i+1][b])<0)
            {
                c1[c]=malloc(strlen(mat[i][a])*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(c1[c],mat[i][a]);
                c++; a++;
            }
            else if(strcmp(mat[i][a],mat[i+1][b])>0)
            {
                c1[c]=malloc(strlen(mat[i+1][b])*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(c1[c],mat[i+1][b]);
                c++; b++;
            }
        }

        while(a<co)
        {
            c1[c]=malloc(strlen(mat[i][a])*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(c1[c],mat[i][a]);
                c++; a++;
        }

        while(b<co)
        {
            c1[c]=malloc(strlen(mat[i+1][b])*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(c1[c],mat[i+1][b]);
                c++; b++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<(r*c);i++)
    {
        printf("Mat ordered : %s \n",c1[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pllease add the definition of the matrix to your question. Note: you malloc 1 byte too few. Note 2 why do you malloc at all, you could refer to the original strings, instead...

Answer (score 1):

Try this with arr1[] and arr2[] the two array input and arr3[] the result and m, n the length of the two array

```
int merge_arrays(char arr1[], char arr2[], char arr3[], int m, int n)
{
   int i,j;
   for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
     arr3[i] = arr1[i];
   }
   for(i = m, j = 0 ; i < m + n; i++, j++)
   {
     arr3[i] = arr2[j];
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the solution is to iterate the function with the array of char[][] as input with for loop